# I cannot get my php session to recall my stored variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have php creating new files that are generated by input by a user (I know not great) I want all documents to be created by the initial input that way theres no variance. I set the varible in the first php script like so

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["FirstName"] = $_POST['FName'];
```

I know that the FName variable works because the first document creates correctly with the correct title
but then on following documents the php does not name the document properly and just leave it blank, here is how I am creating the the file name for other documents

```
session_start();
$my_file = $_SESSION["FirstName"] . 'History.txt';
```

I am unsure as to why it is not working

Answer (score 0):

So I have no idea why but it just started working. 
I have not touched the php scripts as I moved on to other things but it all started working now.